# What is the reason behind blowing the shofar from the side of one's mouth?

Tags: minhag, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar, elul, face

I've been told that the custom is to blow the shofar from the sides of one mouth, rather than like blowing a trumpet.  What is the source for this custom and the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. It and its answer are going to go very well in [*Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/and-revision-and-houses-of-prayer-and-tzedaka-distribute-the-goodness-of-mi-y).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is in the Ramo ([O.C. 585:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2945)) to blow specifically on the right side of the mouth. The Magain Avraham says this is based on the verse ([Zecharia 3:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/k2303.htm)) והשטן עומד על ימינו - the Satan stands on his right side.

Comment: What if the baal tokea is a lefty?  Any difference?

Comment: @BruceJames, yes, the Magain Avraham there says that it should be done on the side opposite where the Teffilin of the hand are worn, so a lefty would reverse sides if they reverse their Teffilin.