# "Shofar" in Elul - Are its laws the same as blowing on R"H?

Tags: halacha, minhag, mitzvah, shofar, elul

Because the blowing of a shofar in [Elul](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/what-is-the-reason-behind-blowing-the-shofar-from-the-side-of-ones-mouth) is a [minhag](http://www.jewishmag.com/71mag/elul/elul.htm) (as per the comments) are there any requirements/rules that limit it? Must it be blown from a kosher shofar (if not, could it be blown from a non-shofar)? Must it be blown in the same way as a blowing for the mitzvah -- from the [side](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/what-is-the-reason-behind-blowing-the-shofar-from-the-side-of-ones-mouth) of the mouth? Does the person who blows it have to meet the same standards (not be deaf, go to mikvah etc)?

While the blowing is a practice (and has [various](http://www.jewishmag.com/71mag/elul/elul.htm) historical sources and precedents) so we might WANT it to mirror the "real" blowing in all ways, it is still not a mitzvah, so what are the parameters/limitations to it?

Comment: Why would you think a tokea has to go to the mikvah??

Comment: @mevaqesh - I think it's only a minhag because it's easier to blow it that way. Have you tried blowing a shofar from the front of the mouth! Impossibly hard!

Comment: @mevaqesh as per the link, it is codified in the Ramo -- would it be similarly recommended for the blowing on Elul?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. Dov Lior bluntly [says](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/16109) one is permitted to blow from an invalid shofar during *Elul*; presumably because it is only a *minhag* and therefore *dinei shofar* don't govern something that isn't halahically required. However, the Belzer dayan, R. SK Gross (Shevet HaKehati vol. 1 §185) suggests, basing himself on Bach, that one should try to "mirror the real blowing". R. Avraham Chafuta (M'aneh Lashon vol. 5, inyanim shonim, §21) is also of the opinion that one should make an effort to blow from a valid *shofar* during *Elul*.